# Handling missing value (na) in tensorflow modeling

Tags: tensorflow, missing-data

I am doing a basic logistic regression using Tensorflow. The input dataset has some missing values. Currently, I am treating it as np.nan and the matrix multiplication for the input and weight vector seems to work. However, the error rate and other metrics seems pretty bad. Is there an internal Tensorflow mechanism to deal with missing value?

Comment: Usually, NaN values caused by evaluating log(0), dividing by zero or too high learning rate. Try to check out those cases. Alsa data normalization/standardization may help.

Comment: I double-checked the input dataset, and containing missing value (no observation) in some field is natural in the dataset.